# Youtube Data API: Get Title and Transcript for each video of a playlist

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im trying to get the Title and transcript of all videos of a playlist. This is the code so far:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

api_key = "************************"

#1.query API 

rq = build("youtube", "v3", developerKey=api_key).playlistItems().list(
        part="contentDetails, snippet",
        playlistId="PL590CCC2BC5AF3BC1",
        maxResults=39,        
        ).execute()
        
#2.Create a list with video Ids and Titles

vid_ids = []
vid_title = []
for item in rq["items"]:
    vid_ids.append(item["contentDetails"]["videoId"])
    vid_title.append(item["snippet"]["title"])

#3.Get transcripts

srt = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcripts(vid_ids)

#4.For each video id extract the Key:"text" from a list of dictionaries 

for i in vid_ids:
    get_key_text = " ".join([a_dict["text"] for a_dict in srt[0][i]])       

#5.Create a dictionary with the title and transcript for each video id

pl_dict = dict(zip(vid_title,get_key_text))

#6.print trancript under title

for key, value in pl_dict.items():
    print(key,"\n", value)
```

When I run it I get this result:

```
Lec 1 | MIT 18.01 Single Variable Calculus, Fall 2007 
 T
Lec 2 | MIT 18.01 Single Variable Calculus, Fall 2007 
 h
Lec 3 | MIT 18.01 Single Variable Calculus, Fall 2007 
 e
Lec 4 | MIT 18.01 Single Variable Calculus, Fall 2007 
  
Lec 5 | MIT 18.01 Single Variable Calculus, Fall 2007 
 f
Lec 6 | MIT 18.01 Single Variable Calculus, Fall 2007 
 o
```

In step 3 I get the transcripts, and the result stored in variable "srt" is a tuple ---> tuple [dict, list]. Also, inside the dictionary there is a list dictionaries (one for each video), containing 3 keys: "text", "start" and "duration".

In step 4 I extract the key: "text" from all dictionaries, join them without the double quotes, and store them in the variable get_key_text. But here´s the problem, the variable stores the transcripts of all the videos in one literal string, so in the next step, when I try to print the title and each transcript I only get the first character, second letter, and so on.

What should I do to print each transcript after its title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation of current output

`get_key_text` is an array of chars (a.k.a. a string, here its value is something like `'The following content is provided under ...'`) while `vid_title` is an array of array of chars (a.k.a. an array of strings, here its is something like `['7K1sB05pE0A', 'ryLdyDrBfvI', ...]`), so when doing `zip(vid_title,get_key_text)` you are creating an array of pair where the first entries are the strings of `vid_title` and the second entries are the chars of (last video transcript as you overwrite at each for iteration) `get_key_text`, so you get something like `[['7K1sB05pE0A', 'T'], ['ryLdyDrBfvI', 'h'], ...]`.

### Solution:

So you should change:

```
for i in vid_ids:
    get_key_text = " ".join([a_dict["text"] for a_dict in srt[0][i]])
```

To:

```
get_key_text = [" ".join([a_dict["text"] for a_dict in srt[0][i]]) for i in vid_ids]
```